# Как правильно (поле-значение) распарсить строку

Tags: java

Как правильно (поле-значение) распарсить строку типа:

```
String line = "Fruit: apple=23, orange=43;"
```

Comment: Приведите пример полного формата данных, который нужно парсить. Или ничего другого не будет, только такой, как вы привели в вопросе?

Comment: Есть класс Fruit (String name, int price), и есть строка. Надо распарсить строку, чтобы потом можно было поместить данные в объект. Будет один,как написано в вопросе.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ничего сложного, пример ниже можно доработать и сделать его универсальным (на данный момент он парсит только приведённый вами пример).

```
String strings = "Fruit: apple=23, orange=43;Fruit: apple=23, orange=43;Fruit: apple=23, orange=43;Fruit: apple=23, orange=43;";
List<Fruit> fruits = new ArrayList<>();

for (String str: strings.split(";")) {
    String necessaryPart = str.substring(str.indexOf(' ')).trim();
    String[] fruitsStrings = necessaryPart.split(", ");

    for (String fruitStr : fruitsStrings) {
        String[] values = fruitStr.split("=");

        Fruit fruit = new Fruit(values[0], Integer.parseInt(values[1]));

        fruits.add(fruit);
    }
}

System.out.println(fruits);
```

Ваш класс:

```
class Fruit {

    private String name;
    private int price;

    public Fruit(String name, int price) {
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
    }

    // getters, setters

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Fruit{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", price=" + price +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! А если строчек с фруктами будет 3?

Comment: @Matty каких строчек? Вы имеете в виду, вот так: `Fruit: apple=23, orange=43, banana=100, raspberry=1337;`? Да сколько угодно.

Comment: Fruit: apple=23, orange=43, banana=100, raspberry=1337;Fruit: apple=23, orange=43, banana=100, raspberry=1337;Fruit: apple=23, orange=43, banana=100, raspberry=1337;

Comment: То есть три Fruit - три экземпляра класса Fruit

Comment: @Matty да, как вы можете увидеть, при каждой итерации создаётся новый экземпляр класса. Если ответ вас удовлетворяет, примите его, как верный — для этого есть галочка чуть левее самого ответа.

Comment: @Matty сейчас поправлю ответ, не сразу увидел ваш пример здесь в комментариях.

Comment: @Matty поправил, можете сами проверить. И вообще, я бы советовал, просто так не копировать, а постараться разобраться и воспроизвести самостоятельно. Это не единственный способ решения вашей задачи, а самый простой из всех и только для этого вашего частного случая.